# Deep cloning in Compact Framework

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, clone

Is it possible to deep clone an object in the compact framework? I was hoping to use IClonable and memberwiseclone() however this only performs a shallow copy.

Any ideas on how to do this please using C# 2.0?

Many thanks,

Morris

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've implemented a deep object copy by making my objects serializable `[Serializable()]` and using the following method.

```
public static ObjectType CopyObject<ObjectType>(ObjectType oObject)
{
  XmlSerializer oSeializer = null;

  // Creates the serializer
  oSeializer = new XmlSerializer(oObject.GetType());

  //Use the stream
  using (MemoryStream oStream = new MemoryStream())
  {
    // Serialize the object
    oSeializer.Serialize(oStream, oObject);

    // Set the strem position
    oStream.Position = 0;

    // Return the object
    return (ObjectType)oSeializer.Deserialize(oStream);
  }
}
```

Comment: Folks,

Thanks for your advice, much appreciated. 

Cheers

Morris

Comment: Just be careful, XML serialization doesn't handle aliasing or cycles.